# Plotting amenities on isochrone map with OSMnx

Tags: python, geopandas, osmnx

I'm trying to plot amenities on top of an isochrone map using OSMnx, but when I run the code I get a (distorted) map showing only the isochrone polygons and no amenities. My code is based on this [example](https://github.com/gboeing/osmnx-examples/blob/main/notebooks/13-isolines-isochrones.ipynb). I'll appreciate any help!

```
import geopandas as gpd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import networkx as nx
import osmnx as ox
from descartes import PolygonPatch
from shapely.geometry import LineString
from shapely.geometry import Point
from shapely.geometry import Polygon

%matplotlib inline

ox.config(log_console=False, use_cache=True)

# configure the place, network type, trip times, and travel speed
place = "Menzelstr. 46, Duisburg, Germany"
network_type = "walk"
trip_times = [5, 10, 15]  # in minutes
travel_speed = 4.5  # walking speed in km/hour

# download the street network
G = ox.graph_from_address(place, network_type=network_type)

# find the centermost node and then project the graph to UTM
gdf_nodes = ox.graph_to_gdfs(G, edges=False)
x, y = gdf_nodes["geometry"].unary_union.centroid.xy
center_node = ox.distance.nearest_nodes(G, x[0], y[0])
G = ox.project_graph(G)

# add an edge attribute for time in minutes required to traverse each edge
meters_per_minute = travel_speed * 1000 / 60  # km per hour to m per minute
for _, _, _, data in G.edges(data=True, keys=True):
    data["time"] = data["length"] / meters_per_minute

# get one color for each isochrone
iso_colors = ox.plot.get_colors(n=len(trip_times), cmap="autumn", start=0, return_hex=True)

# make the isochrone polygons
isochrone_polys = []
for trip_time in sorted(trip_times, reverse=True):
    subgraph = nx.ego_graph(G, center_node, radius=trip_time, distance="time")
    node_points = [Point((data["x"], data["y"])) for node, data in subgraph.nodes(data=True)]
    bounding_poly = gpd.GeoSeries(node_points).unary_union.convex_hull
    isochrone_polys.append(bounding_poly)

# get amenities for place
amenities = ox.geometries_from_address(place, tags={"amenity":True}, dist=1200)

# plot the network, add isochrones as colored descartes polygon patches, then add amenities
fig, ax = ox.plot_graph(
    G, show=False, close=False, edge_color="#999999", edge_alpha=0.2, node_size=0
)
for polygon, fc in zip(isochrone_polys, iso_colors):
    patch = PolygonPatch(polygon, fc=fc, ec="none", alpha=0.6, zorder=-1)
    ax.add_patch(patch)
    
amenities.plot(color="white", markersize=1, ax=ax)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- have used **folium** instead of **matplotlib** to plot.  This allows interaction - layers switched on / off and names of amenities to be shown on hover
- key issue with your solution was mixed CRS.  **osmnx** graph and isochrones are in UTM CRS.  amenities are in EPSG:4386.  This I have solved by setting CRS of **geopandas** data frame that is constructed from **list** of isochrones

```
import folium
import osmnx.utils_graph

# not working as expected...
# m = ox.plot_graph_folium(G, popup_attribute="name", weight=2, color="#8b0000", fit_bounds=True)

# edges ...
m = (
    osmnx.utils_graph.graph_to_gdfs(G, nodes=False)
    .loc[:, ["name", "geometry"]]
    .explore(name="edges", height=400, width=800)
)

# isochrones,  NB CRS
m = gpd.GeoDataFrame(
    {"color": iso_colors, "trip time": trip_times},
    geometry=isochrone_polys,
    crs=G.graph["crs"],
).explore(
    m=m,
    name="isochrones",
    style_kwds={"style_function": lambda p: {"color": p["properties"]["color"]}},
)
# ameneties
m = amenities.loc[:, ["amenity", "name", "geometry"]].explore(
    "amenity", m=m, name="amenities"
)
folium.LayerControl().add_to(m)
m
```

#### output

[image]